# lambda, webpack using node_externals require apollo-server-lambda

Tags: webpack, apollo-server

I'm using webpack with my lambda project which in turn is using 'apollo-server-lambda'.  The problem is that in my webpack file I have the following

```
externals: [nodeExternals({
        whitelist: ['graphql', 'iterall', 'apollo-server-lambda', 'apollo-server-core', 'apollo-server-module-graphiql']
    })],
```

When I run this then in turn gives me the following error

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'graphql-extensions'",
```

Even if I add this then I get another error and so on.

how do I figure out all the dependencies of a particular module and then add it to the whitelist.  I specifically looking for apollo-server-lambda